# What is the physical meaning of the zeroness of the antidiagonal of the matrix representation of $\textbf{n}\cdot\textbf{S}$ operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-interpretations

I encountered a problem where I had to use $\textbf{n}\cdot{\textbf{S}}$. It was found to be:

[image]

What does it mean physically, that the antidiagonal of this matrix is 0, for any $\textbf{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All spin matrices for integer spin *j* have this property in the spherical  basis (not in the Cartesian one, of course).

It is easy to see that. They are $(2j+1)\times (2j+1)$-dimensional matrices.

$S_z$ is diagonal, but its central eigenvalue is 0 (for integer spins).

$S_+$ is a raising operator by one, so only the first parallel above the diagonal is nonzero; however, it has length 2 *j*, so it does not "shadow" the central diagonal 0, and so the second, third, ... parallels vanish, yielding 0s.  The analog argument holds for $S_-$, and hence the linear combinations of raising and lowering operators.

You are done.

As indicated, this is a fluke property of the spherical basis. In the Cartesian basis, you'd have nonzero antidiagonals for $S_y$.  I don't see much physics in a  basis-dependent statement, then.

Comment: *I don't see much physics in a basis-dependent
statement, then.* Well, the spherical basis isn't a basis whatever.
It's a basis of eigenvectors of a component of $\vec S$.

Comment: @Elio Fabri. Correct. A basis then defines the orientation of operators (here, matrices) that act on it, and hence ***defines a basis for these matrices***. Changing the basis of the vectors similarity-transforms the matrices to the corresponding new basis. So, then, contrast $S_z$ in the spherical basis to $L_z$ in the Cartesian basis, as in the first week of angular momentum treatments.